# Why is this transaction schedule not serializable?

Tags: sql, database, serialization, transactions

I'm going over practice problems for my database course.

We are given a transaction schedule:

```
 T1            T2
 Read(A)
               Write(B)
               Commit
 Read(B)
 Write(B)
 Commit(B)
```

The book says that the above is not **serial**, but why?
It seems to me you could run T2 then run T1 and get the same result.

Comment: Are you talking about SQL Server?

Comment: This example is serial, the outcome is equal to the outcome of you run the two  transactions serially

Comment: Maybe an error in the practice question/answer :-|?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of definition--your example is serializable but not serial.

A **Serial Schedule** is a schedule where every transaction happens one at a time.

A **Serializable Schedule** is a schedule that can be converted to a serial schedule while preserving the outcome.

Comment: I've finished the course relevant to this question like a year ago, but it makes me warm and fuzzy inside knowing that someone answered my question.

Comment: Hi Jonah, how would you figure out if something like this is serializable or not?

 EXAMPLES: 
 Schedule 1: T2:R(B), T2:W(B), T1:W(A), T1:R(B), T3:R(A), T1:W(B), T2:W(A)

Schedule 2: T1:R(B), T3:R(A), T3:W(A), T2:R(B), T2:W(A), T3:W(C), T1:R(A), T2:R(C)

Would you usuualy just manually eyeball it, and swap around txns until you're happy the outcome is the same as serial (and if not possible, it's not serializable)  -  I'm not talking about "conflict-serializable" here as I can manage that. any help you can provide is much appreciated (I'm working on a college exam)    . Cheers !